# Create hollow circle with Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

How can I achieve a similar effect like http://jsfiddle.net/Hnw6a/1137/ using Fabric.js?

I tried with `clipTo` but without luck.

I want to update this script http://jsfiddle.net/kxjV5/ to accept 'hollow' circles

Comment: Use [`Path`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Path.html).

Comment: Path doesn't seem to have a 'arc' equal command

Comment: Of course it does — https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/dist/fabric.js#L14359-L14387

Comment: thanks, i was trying the command like Path(arc(xx,xx,xx,xx));

Comment: i can't use path :( , the code currently is like this http://jsfiddle.net/kxjV5/, i tried to make a path with a hollow circle but when its modified with the mouse move i cant reapply the new path over the old one , it just makes a new object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
{
  fill: "none",
  stroke: "red",
  strokeWidth: 5
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eguneys/kxjV5/

Comment: In the actual implementation the background is variable the user can paint behind the circle or change the background.This could work with fill opacity though and i don't think this is possible... hmm maybe fill-rule ?

Comment: omg i can't believe how i didn't think of that... :S thank you you saved my day

Comment: Please note that fill:"none" doesn't work on firefox correctly, using fill : "transparent" , works on chrome and firefox ok

Answer (score 1):

Well this one is not working on Chrome for sure.

```
{
  fill: "none",//should be fill:undefined
  stroke: "red",
  strokeWidth: 5
}
```

The fill should be set to `undefined`, not `none`.

Answer (score 0):

If  `fill: "none"` doesn't work, try this:

```
{
 fill: "rgba(0,0,0,0.0)", //setting alpha channel to 0.0 will make fill transparent
 stroke: "red", 
 strokeWidth: 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actual working solutions, that I found

```js
{
 fill: 'transparent',
 // or: fill: undefined,
 // or: fill: "rgba(0,0,0,0.0)", //setting alpha channel to 0.0 will make fill transparent

 stroke: "red", 
 strokeWidth: 5
}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/1dvcrxa8/